# UWP Grid do not fill parent container

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

I've got a big problem and I can't figure out how to solve it. I have a xaml layout:

```
<Hub x:Name="MainHub" DataContext="{x:Bind Model}" Margin="108,30,0,0">
            <Hub.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderTemplate">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="26" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="#4B5054"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Hub.Resources>
            <HubSection Header="News">
                <HubSection.HeaderTemplate>
                    <StaticResource ResourceKey="HeaderTemplate"/>
                </HubSection.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="0,4,0,0">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <controls:VariableGridView x:Name="NewsGrid" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding News}">
                            <GridView.Resources>
                                <DataTemplate x:Key="NewsItemTemplate">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="188*" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="50*" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="57*" />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                            <controls:WebImage ImageUri="{Binding Image, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                        <Grid Background="#802A2B2D" Grid.Row="1">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title, Mode=OneWay}" Foreground="#D7D7D7" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                        <Grid Background="White" Grid.Row="2">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, Mode=OneWay}" Foreground="#2A2B2D" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridView.Resources>
                            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <VariableSizedWrapGrid x:Name="TestGrid" Orientation="Vertical" MaximumRowsOrColumns="2" 
                                                       ItemWidth="{Binding Width, ElementName=DummyNews, Mode=OneWay}" ItemHeight="{Binding Height, ElementName=DummyNews, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                                <StaticResource ResourceKey="NewsItemTemplate"/>
                            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                            <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
                                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 15 15"/>
                                </Style>
                            </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        </controls:VariableGridView>
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="More >" FontSize="26" FontWeight="Light" Margin="0,0,15,0" Foreground="#4B5054" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>                
            </HubSection>
            <HubSection Header="Featured Products">
                <HubSection.HeaderTemplate>
                    <StaticResource ResourceKey="HeaderTemplate"/>
                </HubSection.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </HubSection>
        </Hub>
```

I have VariableSizedWrapGrid's width and height bound to code-behind models (item size changes when I resize a window):

```
ItemHeightVM.Value = (e.NewSize.Height - 200) / 2;
ItemWidthVM.Value = ItemHeightVM.Value / NEWS_WH_ASPECT;
```

This part working, but grid, specified in VariableGridView's data template don't fill whole item:

[Widht and height not specified, grid do not fill parent container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXsoO.png)

But when I bind grid's width and height to my code-behind VM, or just specify width and height values, I've got right item size and right layouting, but only if item's rowspan and colspan are 1:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="NewsItemTemplate">
  <Grid Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=DummyNews, Mode=OneWay}" Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=DummyNews, Mode=OneWay}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="188*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="50*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="57*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

When colspan or rowspan are 2 or more, margins are back :(

[Bound to view model, colspan set to 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXay4.png)

Please, tell me how can I remove those margins and stretch my grid to fill whole item container if colspan (or rowspan) will be set to 2 or more? Hope that you can help me, I tried to solve this issue for a couple of hours and gave up

Comment: Could you please upload all code? Since your issue mainly because the VariableGridView. We cannot test it. Especially the  VariableGridView . When colspan or rowspan set to 2, set which control? So the last effect you want is no margin for the two parts?